# JavaScript does not remove all elements in one iteration, even when the condition is always satisfied

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I am trying to compare two arrays with multiple objects in them, and remove elements based on a condition. I tried first in the chrome's console, and was shocked to find for some reason, the arr1 is not getting empty even when I am using an if condition that clearly is always true. After the first iteration, I always see atleast one object being left out, and after running the loop many times, it gets removed. Am I missing something? This seems such a basic JavaScript error.

```js
var car1 = {
  type: 'das',
  model: '1',
  color: 'blue'
} //sample object
arr1 = []
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  arr1[i] = car1
} //filling object with values

for (i in arr1) {
  if (arr1[i].type == 'das') { //removing element with condition which always matches
    arr1.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: removing elements changes the indices of the following items.

Comment: @NinaScholz so how should I alter my code that it does not happen? Use a temp array?

Comment: iterate it backwards. ie `for (let i = arr1.length-1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: Your array is numerically indexed, so there is no real need to use a for-in loop to begin with … a simple for loop, going over the elements _in reverse order_, is a simple solution for situations like this.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you, that solved my issue in one iteration, using no temprorary space and it is simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not change array value in its loop.

```js
var car1 = {
  type: 'das',
  model: '1',
  color: 'blue'
} //sample object
arr1 = []
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  arr1[i] = car1
} //filling object with values
arr2 = [];
for (i in arr1) {
  if (arr1[i].type != 'das') { //removing element with condition which always matches
    arr2.push(arr1[i]);
  }
}
arr1 = arr2
console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: Using temp object was also something I tried, but it seemed unnecassary.